# does blender have full body motion tracking?

Tags: motion-capture

Im trying to find out if theres full body motion tracking and rigging because i want to use my own body movement in blender animation, i dont want to download others motion captured stuff. i dont want to use a kinect camera for motion tracking my character movement. is there a way to track the full body to use in animating a human like character only using a dslr camera not a kinect?
 [image]

Comment: like not using a kinect camera. only using a normal dslr to track the body move ment of a person to use in animating a character is it possible in blender?

Comment: The Kinect delivers 3D coordinates and a DSLR delivers 2D images (or sequences of them). I don't think there is another solution, other than using your video as a background video and "mocap" the movements manually. Neither Blender nor any other 3D animation software has a "magic one button" solution for such a thing. The Kinect+DSLR combo is so popular, because it delivers quite good results for the price tag.

Comment: so there is a chance in this vid he used a kinect not just 2 cameras? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lIrM3sscxxE